# Django multiple sites with apache mod_wsgi: Request going to wrong site

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

I am trying to run 2 Django sites from one apache server using virtual hosts with `mod_wsgi`. The problem is that all my request are going to the same Django site(probably the first one loaded by Apache) even when I use the hostname for the other site. My sites are

```
https://staging-test.mydomain.com
```

and

```
https://staging.mydomain.com
```

Here is the content of my virtual hosts files. I have created the two files for deployment which I place in the `site-enabled` directory of my Apache installation(Ubuntu). Two files because it helps in dev-ops. Regardless, the config looks like

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName https://staging-test.mydomain.com
    SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp
    WSGIDaemonProcess https://staging-test.mydomain.com user=www-data group=www-data processes=10 threads=1 python-path=/home/talha/site1 display-name=wsgid
    WSGIProcessGroup https://staging-test.mydomain.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/talha/site1/wsgi.py process-group=https://staging-test.mydomain.com application-group=%{RESOURCE}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName https://staging.mydomain.com
    SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp
    WSGIDaemonProcess https://staging.mydomain.com user=www-data group=www-data processes=10 threads=1 python-path=/home/talha/site2 display-name=wsgid
    WSGIProcessGroup https://staging.mydomain.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/talha/site2/wsgi.py process-group=https://staging.mydomain.com application-group=%{RESOURCE}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried to use the `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup` to make the sites run in different processes, however the requests are still going to only one of them.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: remove `https://` from `ServerName`

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out, your initial problem is that you should not use a URI in the ServerName, it must be just the host name. Beyond fixing that, then make sure you read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

You are hitting a variation of the default VirtualHost problem described in that post due to wrong setting for ServerName.

Comment: I removed `https` from the `ServerName` and now they are `staging.mydomain.com` and `staging-test.mydomain.com`. The hostname of the system is `staging.mydomain.com`. I still face the same issue. Can you explain what the variation is which you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: As is described in the blog post, if Apache doesn't match the request to a VirtualHost it will fallback to using the first VirtualHost that Apache found when reading its configuration file. So if a request intended to be handled by the second VirtualHost doesn't match, it would use the first above if that was the first Apache saw. One possible cause could be because you are using '``_default_``' instead '*' as I wouldn't expect to see that in this case.